# make pycurl use different curl/libcurl installation

Tags: libcurl, osx-leopard, pycurl

I've got two installations of curl: one is in /usr/bin - should be the system one, another is in /usr/local/bin - I installed it from source. These two installations have different versions.

Pycurl is using the one from /usr/bin, whereas curl command now points to the one in /usr/local/bin - I've changed the $PATH var in my .bash_profile accordingly.

I didn't try to re-install pycurl.

Is there a way to tell pycurl to use the different libcurl installation, the one which comes along with /usr/local/bin/curl?
If pycurl re-installing is required, are there any additional flags needed to point pycurl to the needed libcurl version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you install pycurl by hand (setup.py, not pip), you can run:

```
python setup.py --curl-config=/usr/local/bin/curl-config install
```

(To install with pip, I would try moving `/usr/local/bin` first in your path so it will find the right curl-config, but I haven't tried this myself)  If your installation of curl is not in `/usr/local`, you might also need to add the appropriate lib directory to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using python virtualenv could be of help.